# JPA 2 with Hibernate escapes Strings

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a funny situation, where hibernate/jpa seems to escape \n with \\n:

String in DB: Hello World\nDude
String after entitymanager get in my POJO: Hello World\\nDude

can I get rid of this escaping funcionality?

Hmm..

Actually found the problem..

My Editor (MySQL Workbench) automatically escapes \n if you edit the table directly.
Therefore the escaping is from the MySQL Workbench and Java acts quite right :).

Comment: The only difference I see is that the first one contains `World`, whereas the second one contains `Wolrd`. Neither that nor the \n escape is cause by Hibernate. Check your own code.

Comment: Sorry, again an escaping porblem.. now corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found the problem..

My Editor (MySQL Workbench) automatically escapes \n if you edit the table directly. Therefore the escaping is from the MySQL Workbench and Java acts quite right :).